# D3 - Help Required in d3.nest

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've got a d3.nest function which gives me the data in the following format.

```
    [
      {
        "key": "Level1",
        "values": [
          {
            "x": 118,
            "y": 106,
            "size": 1.113207547
          },
          {
            "x": 111,
            "y": 137,
            "size": 0.810218978
          },
          {
            "x": 144,
            "y": 195,
            "size": 0.738461538
          },
          {
            "x": 116,
            "y": 129,
            "size": 0.899224806
          },
          {
            "x": 117,
            "y": 119,
            "size": 0.983193277
          },
          {
            "x": 145,
            "y": 122,
            "size": 1.18852459
          }
        ],
         "slope": 0.52289599949494,
        "intercept": 0.2795214697252959
      },
      {
        "key": "Level2",
        "values": [
          {
            "x": 172,
            "y": 193,
            "size": 0.89119171
          },
          {
            "x": 138,
            "y": 114,
            "size": 1.210526316
          },
          {
            "x": 106,
            "y": 189,
            "size": 0.560846561
          },
          {
            "x": 123,
            "y": 141,
            "size": 0.872340426
          },
          {
            "x": 129,
            "y": 110,
            "size": 1.172727273
          },
          {
            "x": 162,
            "y": 198,
            "size": 0.818181818
          }
        ],
         "slope": 0.52289599949494,
        "intercept": 0.2795214697252959
      },
      {
        "key": "Level3",
        "values": [
          {
            "x": 191,
            "y": 104,
            "size": 1.836538462
          },
          {
            "x": 177,
            "y": 186,
            "size": 0.951612903
          },
          {
            "x": 106,
            "y": 140,
            "size": 0.757142857
          },
          {
            "x": 131,
            "y": 161,
            "size": 0.813664596
          },
          {
            "x": 111,
            "y": 128,
            "size": 0.8671875
          },
          {
            "x": 149,
            "y": 122,
            "size": 1.221311475
          },
          {
            "x": 200,
            "y": 126,
            "size": 1.587301587
          }
        ],
         "slope": 0.52289599949494,
        "intercept": 0.2795214697252959
      }
    ]
```

I'd want to exclude only the "type" from the values. Somebody help me on how to do it.

Function i used to get that data is below.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.x = +d.x
                    d.y = +d.y
                    d.size = +d.size
                })

                var nest = d3.nest()
                            .key(function(d) {return d.type;})
                            .rollup(function(v) {return v.map(function(d) {return d})})
                            .entries(data);

               d3.select('body').append('pre')
               .text(JSON.stringify(nest, null, '  '));
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want `type` to be present in returned array, you can `delete` it while doing the `rollUp`:

```js
.rollUp(function (v) { return v.map(function (d) { delete d.type; return d; })
```

Do note that it will referentially delete 'type' from the original data set as well. If you do not want that to happen, then [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or otherwise clone the data in the `rollUp` function.

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot. And when i observed there was no changes done in the csv file.

Comment: Hey i just wanted another help. Once the level1 is finished it's getting continued to level2. Before level2 starts I wanted to add 2 more variables after the values field for each levels. How do i do it?

Comment: `.rollUp(function (v) { return v.map(function (d) { delete d.type; d.extra1 = v1; d.extra2 = v2; return d; })`. And I meant the `data` variable, not the `csv` file when I said that _original data set_.

Comment: When you said the original data i meant the csv file. Anyways I tried with what you've given in the above comment. But couldn't succeed. I've updated post in the data format section. You'll find two new variables `slope` and `intersect` where these values are generated using Math.randon() d3 function.

Comment: Please post it as a new question. Thanks.

Comment: [**Here you go**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833322/d3-nest-adding-extra-variables)